# Bleib nicht bei ihm

Tags: meaning, preposition

This is a sentence from Duolingo. The app translates it as "don't stay with him". Does this mean *don't stay at his place* or *break up with him*?

Comment: I'd say the latter.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Bleib nicht mit ihm"? I thought 'bei' was used to mean staying at someone's place.

Comment: No, this would be very uncommon. In this case it's not about location at all, but the relationship stands focussed.

Comment: @user392289: No, because "mit jemandem sein" is quite unidiomatic. If anything, you can say "mit jemandem zusammen sein" (in which case your suggestion should read "Bleib nicht mit ihm zusammen"), and then the meaning is even somewhat more clearly (if not absolutely exclusively) about relationship status. The only occasion where "mit jemandem sein" is typically used is as somewhat archaic language in religious contexts, such as "Gott ist mit dir." (and this, obviously, does not point out romantic relationship status, but rather being on/at someone's side or ready to support them).

Comment: Note, Duolingo has its own discussion forum, so see [the thread for this question](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/20378093) as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can mean both depending on the context. But it more often means *break up with him*. It would mean *don't stay at his place* if someone had explicitly asked about staying with him in a specific situation e.g. staying in his flat for this night. The (warning) answer could be *Nein, bleib nicht bei ihm*. But this is not as often.

To express the request to leave the place next to him it's common and natural to add a verb, which describes the action the addressee does in order to keep the place, e.g. *Bleib nicht bei ihm stehen* if the addressee stands next to him or *Bleib nicht bei ihm sitzen* if the addressee sits next to him.